# Upgrade questions

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, bios, performance-tuning

Hi I just upgraded from i5-3450s with Intel HD 2500 to i7-3770s with Intel HD 4000. I also increased RAM from 8GB to 16GB.  I have an HP Omni 27.

Windows 7, x64
Direct X Version is 11.0, 
Shader Version 5, 
Open GL 1.1,
Intel HD 4000 Video Bios is 2126,
MotherBoard is HP Pegatron ipisb-nk (lavaca3-sb) (but CPU-Z says it is 2 ADC), Bios is AMI 8.17
Chipset is Intel Series 6, Ivy Bridge, H61

I choose to use the Intel generic driver version 10.18.10.4358 because the HP custom driver gives me more problems.

After installation I expected bios video bios setting to increase relative to the upgrade. So, after upgrade I still have Total Available Graphics at 1696 MB, Dedicated memory at 64 MB, System Video Memory at 0 MB, and Shared System Memory at 1632 MB.

Bios is fixed, locked, whatever, tried to find backdoor or secret advanced bios setting without success.

Shouldn't my video setting have increased after my upgrade? I feel that since I doubled the processor and RAM power, my video settings should have increased to.

Yes. This has to do with gaming...and principle.

Comment: The amount of shared VRAM is based on the motherboard and BIOS, you didn't change either, so the maximum VRAM wouldn't have changed.

Comment: Oh, my. I was so hoping. I'm gonna find a way to get in that bios.

Comment: HD 4000 is still a poor choice for gaming. It's not the memory that will be a limiting factor, but GPU's computational power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1696Mb is the maximum for HD4000 too, significant differencies are only in frequencies and execution units counts